# Google Sheets multiple passwords

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following appscript in my google sheets which asks user to input the password to access the file.

```
function openSheets(){
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().hideRows(3, 31);
  hideAllSheetsExcept('Sheet1')
}

function hideAllSheetsExcept(sheetName) {

  var sheets=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i =0;i<sheets.length;i++){
    Logger.log(i);
    if(sheets[i].getName()!=sheetName){
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
  var quest="";
  while (quest!='123'){
    quest = Browser.inputBox("Enter password");
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().showRows(3, 31);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B5').activate();
}
```

I want to share this with my friends like 3 of them. But I want to give them each a different password to access this. How can I change this code to accept multiple passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  const pw = ['123', '456', '789'];
  while (!pw.includes(quest)){
    quest = Browser.inputBox("Enter password");
  }
```

Reference:

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)